# objective c Strong&Weak relationship when doing assignment

Tags: objective-c

I am currently reading apple documentation of objective c programming. In a chapter that explain Strong & Weak Relationship , there is a part saying:

Local variables (and non-property instance variables) also maintain strong references to objects by default. This means that the following code will work exactly as you expect:

```
NSDate *originalDate = self.lastModificationDate;
self.lastModificationDate = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Last modification date changed from %@ to %@",
                    originalDate, self.lastModificationDate);
```

In this example, **the local variable originalDate maintains a strong reference to the initial lastModificationDate object. When the lastModificationDate property is changed, the property no longer keeps a strong reference to the original date**, but that date is still kept alive by the originalDate strong variable.

I am very confused that :
originalDate maintains a strong reference to lastModificationDate and it said lastModificationDate also keeps a strong reference to original date, that means **they keep strong relationship with each other(strong cycle?)**

is this understanding correct? 
My question is , can you give a graph about relationship between two objects when there is an assignment like this:

```
NSDate *originalDate = self.lastModificationDate;
```

who has a reference to who??
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's some subtlety in the language being used there. Keep in mind that `originalDate` is the variable shown in the code. And the words "original date" is simply a statement about whatever original (the starting) value the variable was referencing.

In other words, don't confuse the mentioning of the variable `originalDate` with the words "original date" which refers to whatever date value a variable was referencing in the beginning.

To help clarify, you need to understand that objects (such as an instance of an `NSDate`) resides in memory. Think of it as a ball you can stand in front of an point to. And this ball is labeled "Original NSDate instance".

Now have a person stand in front of this ball and point at the ball. Label this person "self.lastModificationDate". In code this would be something like `self.lastModification = [NSDate date];`.

Now you come across the line of code `NSDate *originalDate = self.lastModificationDate;`. In our analogy this means we add a second person and we label the person "originalDate". The line of code is saying that `originalDate` now points to the same object that `self.lastModificationDate` is pointing to. So have our second person also point to the same ball. So there are now two people pointing to the same ball labeled "Original NSDate instance".

Now you get the line of code `self.lastModificationDate = [NSDate date];`. This does two things. First it creates a new `NSDate` instance. It creates a new ball in our analogy. Label this new ball "Second NSDate instance". Second, this changes the ball that the person labeled "self.lastModificationDate" is pointing to. So imagine now that that person stops pointing at the original ball and is now pointing to the new ball. But keep in mind that the person labeled "originalDate" is still pointing to the first ball (the "original date" mentioned in the confusing text).

Summary. After the two lines of code:

```
NSDate *originalDate = self.lastModificationDate;
self.lastModificationDate = [NSDate date];
```

we have two balls and two people. Each person is pointing to a different ball. The person labeled "self.lastModificationDate" is pointing to the new ball labeled "Second NSDate instance" and the person labeled "originalDate" is pointing to the original ball labeled "Original Date instance".

And the line of code

```
NSLog(@"Last modification date changed from %@ to %@",
                originalDate, self.lastModificationDate);
```

verifies this by showing you that two different dates are logged. The one referenced by the `originalDate` variable and the new one referenced by `self.lastModificationDate`.

So again, think of variables as people and think of objects as balls that the people point to. People can point to either no ball or one ball. And multiple people can point to the same ball. You can even end up with cases where a ball has no one pointing to it. This is called a "memory leak".

The above doesn't really cover "strong" and "weak'. So we are going to expand the analogy a little. Imagine a strong reference as a person actually holding onto a ball. And imagine a weak reference as a person simply pointing at the ball. As long as at least one person is holding onto a ball (a strong reference), the ball stays in place. If a ball gets to the point where no one is holding it anymore (no more strong references), the ball falls and disappears (the object gets deallocated). This is true even if there are people (weak references) pointing to it. In these cases, the people that were simply pointing at it are now pointing to nothing (the weak references become `nil`).

Answer (score 0):

I've put your code in a method and added comments at each step.  Let `Date1` be the first NSDate `self.lastModificationDate` references. Let `Date2` be the second NSDate `self.lastModificationDate` references.

```
-(void)printDates 
{
    // self.lastModificationDate: holds a strong reference to Date1
    // originalDate: does not exist yet

    NSDate *originalDate = self.lastModificationDate;

    // self.lastModificationDate : still holds a strong reference to Date1
    // originalDate: holds a strong reference to Date1

    self.lastModificationDate = [NSDate date];

    // self.lastModificationDate : now holds a strong reference Date2
    // originalDate: still holds a strong reference to Date1

    NSLog(@"Last modification date changed from %@ to %@",
                    originalDate, self.lastModificationDate);

    return;

    // The method has returned so originalDate releases its strong reference to Date1

    // self.lastModificationDate : still holds a strong reference to Date2
    // originalDate: does not exist

    // At this point there are no strong references to Date1 so Date1 is released
}
```